# A VIM search/replace pattern

Tags: vim

How do I do a VIM search/replace with the following conditions:

a) the line contains str1

b) the line also contain str2

c) the line do NOT contain str3

on such a line, I do want to replace xxx with yyy

Comment: Better to post sample inputs and desired outputs. There might be an easier way to do it than what you have in mind.

Comment: OK here is an input line: **return aLib.getSomething()**. That line need to become **return aLib.getSomething(aHandle)**. Referring to the question, str1 is "return" str2 is "aLib". str3 is "aHandle" and the replace string is "()". I need to replace **many** of these patterns.

Comment: I'm going to make a probably-incorrect assumption and assume that you just hit enter in an attempt to enter a newline into your comment. Hold shift while hitting enter to insert a newline in a comment.

Comment: Just to confirm, are the strings always in the same order?

Comment: One can assume the order is always the same, yes.

Comment: g/return aLib/s/return aLib.getSomething()/return    aLib.getSomething(aHandle)

Comment: @TotteKarlsson oh, didn't check the comments. why don't you write example text in question?? anyway, take a look my answer, I think you could replace those xxx,yyy,str123 etc. with your real data.

Comment: +1 why the question gets downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

regex doesn't handle `and, not` very well. there are ways to do it, but bit tricky. A very simple function could solve your problem:

```
function! Rep()
        let l = getline('.')
        if stridx(l, 'str1')>=0 && stridx(l,'str2') >=0 && stridx(l,'str3')<0
                execute 's/xxx/yyy/g'
        endif
endfunction
```

you can

- either write it in your `.vimrc` file.
- or save it in a `foo.vim` file and open it with vim type `:so %`

then open your target file, type `:%call Rep()` you will see for example:

```
str1 str2 str3 xxx
str3 str2 xxx
str2 xxx
*str1 str2 xxx
*xxx str2 xxx str2 xxx str1
```

would be changed into:

```
str1 str2 str3 xxx
str3 str2 xxx
str2 xxx
*str1 str2 yyy
*yyy str2 yyy str2 yyy str1
```

I think replacing str1,str2,xxx,yyy to your real values in that function isn't hard for you, is it?

**EDIT**

your real problem seems to be much easier than the problem you described in question. try this line:

```
:%s/\(\s*return\s*aLib\.[^(]\+(\)\s*\()\)/\1aHandle\2/
```

Note that it could be written shorter only for your example working, but I want it to be secure.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman this works for his real input too. it is supposed to be generic solution. and order doesn't matter.

Comment: I know. The versatile nature of your answer is what makes it excellent.

Comment: your real problem seems to be much easier than the problem in your question. check the EDIT in answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will replace the `()` string in every line of a file containing the string `return` and the string `aLib` at some point after that:

```
:%s/return.*aLib.*\zs()\ze/(aHandle)/
```

The `%` is the operating range of the command, which includes all lines in the file.

`\zs` denotes the start of the replaced string and `\ze` denotes its end.

If you have to replace more than one instance per line, put a `g` at the end of the command after the last `/`. If you wish to confirm each substitution, put the `c` flag at the end.

By assuming the `()` string is never present if `aHandle` is present, this command doesn't answer your question exactly, but based on the sample provided in the comments, this may match your needs.

Comment: where is `not str3` part? e.g. my string is `return aHandle.aLib()` ?

Comment: I'll try that out.  Fact is that if the line contains a (), it don't contain str3 so it should work..

Comment: That was my reasoning. I have modified my answer to be more clear about the command's behavior in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

I think **@Kent**'s answer (the function) is the "most correct" when doing complex searches/substitutions. It's easier to change afterward, and to understand it also after a while, it's also quicker to write than this. But I think it can be interesting if it's possible to do this with a "oneliner".
I welcome comments about this not working, I find it interesting myself if it's possible, **not** if it's the "best solution".

A "oneliner" for all situations described in the original question.

```
:v/str3/s/\v(.*str1&.*str2)@=.{-}\zsxxx/yyy/g
```

**Explanation:**

- `:v/str3/` all lines NOT containing "`str3`"
- `s/` substitute
- `\v` "very magic" (to not have to escape regex expressions like `{}`), [`:h \v`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cv)
- `(.*str1&.*str2)@=` positive look-ahead, [`:h \@=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@=)

  - `.*str1` any character 0 or more ("greedy") followed by "`str1`", the preceding `.*` is important for both `&` and `@=` to work
  - `&` pattern before and after `&` must be present, different than `|` that is using "or", both patterns **must** start at same place, thats why `.*` is used before `str1/2`, [`:h \&`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C&)
  - `@=` the atom before (in the parentheses) should be present, but the pattern is not included in the match, the atom must however start at the beginning of the line for this to work (`.*` makes sure of that).
- `.{-}` any character 0 or more ("not greedy"), `{-}` instead of `*` is important if more than one occurrence of `xxx` should be substituted (not enough with the `g` flag in this case)
- `\zs` sets the start of the match (what to substitute).
- `xxx` finally, the string to substitute
- `/yyy/` replace the match with `yyy`
- `g` all occurences on the line

This gives the same result as using the example in @Kent's answer, it will handle any order of `str1`, `str2`, `str3` and `xxx`.
I repeat that this is an alternative if for some reason a function is not an alternative.  As I understand OP, e.g. `str2` is always after `str1` in his case, so this is more a general solution for situations like this (and perhaps more of academic interest).